# Convert JSON Table to XML Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, xml, sql-server-2014

How can I convert **ALL** JSON columns [`nvarchar(max)`] from `TableJSON` to XML columns in `TableXML` when `TableJSON` is update or inserted into (in a trigger)?

Get all `nvarchar(max)` columns:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(max)

SELECT @COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableJSON' 
  AND DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nvarchar' 
  AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 --NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Convert JSON to XML:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

TableJSON:

```
   ID        bigint,
   Code      char(10),
   Field1    nvarchar(max),
   ...
   Field100  nvarchar(max)
```

TableXML:

```
   ID        bigint,
   Code      char(10),
   Field1    xml,
   ...
   Field100  xml
```

My trigger (currently only for `Field1`):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateXMLTable]
ON [dbo].[TableJSON]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID bigint
    DECLARE @Field1 nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @MyHierarchy Hierarchy,@Field1XML XML

    SELECT  @ID = ID,
            @Field1 = Field1
    FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO @myHierarchy
    SELECT * FROM parseJSON(@Field1)
    SELECT dbo.ToXML(@MyHierarchy)
    SET @Field1XML = dbo.ToXML(@MyHierarchy)

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[TableXML] WHERE ID = @ID)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableXML] (ID, Field1) VALUES (@ID, @Field1XML)
    ELSE 
        IF (UPDATE (Field1))
            UPDATE [dbo].[TableXML] SET Field1 = @Field1XML WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

How can I convert **ALL** JSON columns from `TableJSON` to XML columns in `TableXML`?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT .... FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!